# Laravel - Auth optional?

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes

I have some endpoints in REST API that use Auth::id() as optional field. I mean action may be called both by guest and logged in user. Now, if I put route outside `auth:api` middleware it works but `Auth::id()` is returning null even if bearer header was sent. When I move routing to `auth:api` it works as intended for logged in user but obviously is not accessible for guests.

As a workaround I can create 2 similar endpoints (one for guests, one for logged users) but duplicating endpoints looks wrong :/

Comment: if `api` isn't your default guard then it will try to use the default guard when calling `Auth::id()` since the auth middleware isn't there to change the default to `api` it will hit the default

Comment: right, I completely forgot about guards... Auth::guard('api')->id() works :) Thanks!